# Responsive, horizontal scrolling of fully-sized images

Tags: html, css, image, scroll

I'm trying to implement a responsive horizontally scrolled list of images.

For example:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="image1.jpg"/>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="image2.jpg"/>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="image3.jpg"/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The images are an unknown width and height ratio.

**My Requirements**:

1. I want the images to always be 100% height of the browser window at all times.
2. I want them to be adjacent to each other (without using `float`; so `inline` is probably best).
3. I don't want to break the width/height ratio of the images on window resize.
4. No javascript.

So far I've tried with this CSS, but I can't seem to get the images not to squash when the browser window is resized:

```
ul{

  width:100%;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;

}

ul li{

  display:inline;

  height:100%;

}

ul li img{

  max-height:100%;
  width:auto;

}
```

Any takers?

**Edit**:

I've put a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vZ4p/) together for an example of where I'm at with it.

Any help would be great...

Comment: Why won't you use `float`?

Comment: if you want to force the width to 100%, then set `width: 100%`

Comment: @Mooseman because I will have to calculate parent width in JavaScript in order that the images don't wrap, unless you're suggesting I get funky with some `overflow:hidden` and some wrapping elements? If you think you can mirror the effect with float (and no absolute widths) then by all means put it in an answer.

Comment: @koala_dev That's nowhere near what I want. The size of my images should be responsive to the `height` of the window.

Comment: Your requirement reads: "I want the images to always be 100% of the browser window." you should clarify that's height, not width

Comment: @koala_dev Fair enough. Have edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay here we go. After much experimentation I've finally found what I believe to be the answer for most browsers. Seems to work on Firefox 3.5+, Safari 4+, Chrome 3+. I've also tested on an iOS device, an Android device, and IE, though not extensively.

*clears throat*

```
html, body{

  width:100%;
  height:100%;

}

html, body, ul, li{

  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  border:0;

  text-decoration:none;

}

ul{

  width:100%;
  height:100%; /* CHANGE */

  overflow-y:scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;

}

ul li{

  display:inline;

  height:100%;

}

ul li img{

  max-height:100%;
  height:100%; /* CHANGE */
  width:auto !important; /* CHANGE */

}
```

The main factors seem to be making sure that the `height` properties are `100%` all the way down to the last node in the list, including the `img` (on top of it's `max-height` declaration).

I've also noticed better success in older browsers appending the `!important` declaration after the `width:auto` property.

I'm surprised at the lack of hunger for a layout like this, so if this has helped anybody then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you mean by the distortion at low widths when using the %. So one solution would be to also implement some fallback absolute widths too, so that at lower resolutions the images don't re-size.

**CSS**

```
html, body{

    width:100%;
    height:100%;

}

html, body, ul, li{

    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border:0;  
    text-decoration:none;

}

ul{
    min-width:150px
    width:100%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;

}

ul li{

    display:inline;
    height:100%;
}

ul li img{

    min-width:150px
    max-height:100%;
    width:auto;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MkLd4/

Comment: The point at which it begins to squash the image is completely down to the browser size when you first open the page. Using fallback widths (apart from not actually working - see your fiddle) is not a viable option as the behaviour of the CSS is completely unreliable.

Comment: Then it would seem there's no option... If you don't want to use CSS or JS to achieve it and actually  the fiddle does work the images no longer adjust according to the % value when the browser width is < 150px ...