# How to horizontally scroll the square boxes present in a row in html/css?

Tags: html, css, scroll, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n1mo8trb/7/embedded/result/) which looks extremely good in the desktop view as shown below:

[image]

The snippets of CSS codes which I have used in order to horizontally align the square boxes in a row are:

```
.squares {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items:center;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 1080px;
  margin: auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what CSS codes I should add in the fiddle so that I am able to horizontal scroll the square boxes in a mobile view similar to this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just view Horizontal scrolling of images. This functionality is present on many websites in accordance with affiliation reference

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832025/responsive-horizontal-scrolling-of-fully-sized-images?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `overflow-y: auto` to the`.squares` div and remove the 
  `flex-wrap: wrap`.

Look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e6gkejud/2/)

You should also provide a `min-width: 150px` to the `.squares .square`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want the desktop view to look exactly the same as present in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n1mo8trb/7/embedded/result/) but in the mobile view the same content should scroll horizontally.

Comment: In your fiddle, it looks like the width and height of a square box is getting distorted.

Comment: See here [https://jsfiddle.net/e6gkejud/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/e6gkejud/2/). Update `min-width: 300px` to `150px`

Comment: looks good but is coming under desktop view. I think we need to add CSS codes in the media queries in order to scroll the squares in the mobile view. I think the codes will go inside this `@media (min-width: 960px) {



  
}` but I am not sure what codes will go inside it. Sorry I am not good with media queries.

Comment: With the `overflow-y: auto` the scrollbar appears only when necessary, so basically in mobile devices. In desktop you should not notice any difference from your original fiddle. Try openening [this embedded fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e6gkejud/2/embedded/)

Comment: Looks good but in the desktop view I am still seeing the scroll whereas I want the scroll to show up only in mobile view.

Comment: Which brower are you using? Are you running Windows or macOS?

Comment: I am using Chrome/Windows.

Comment: There you go I have created the [link](http://ferhan.ferohost.com/) for that. In the mobile view, I want the *squares to scroll*. If you do *CTRL+U*, you can see all the codes behind it ( I am pretty sure, you know it :)). Let me know what code I should enter in the media queries so that the squares scroll in the mobile view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171638/discussion-between-user5447339-and-giacomo-de-liberali).